# LUIS doesn't recognize Japanese intent

Tags: azure-language-understanding

English models recognized sample utterance correctly, but some Japanese models could not recognize them.
Especially when we add the entities to the intent, Japanese language models are very poor scores against the sample utterances.

Answer (score 0):

Japanese isn't fully supported yet; [Named Entity Recognition is currently in Preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/language-support#language-list-and-status).

It's also important to note:

> [Because LUIS does not provide syntactic analysis and will not understand the difference between Keigo and informal Japanese, you need to incorporate the different levels of formality as training examples for your applications.
> でございます is not the same as です.
> です is not the same as だ.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-language-support#japanese-support-notes)

and that:

> [LUIS breaks an utterance into tokens based on culture.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-language-support#tokenization)
>
> [Several cultures return the entity object with the entity value tokenized. The startIndex and endIndex returned by LUIS in the entity object do not map to the new, tokenized value but instead to the original query in order for you to extract the raw entity programmatically.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-data-extraction#tokenized-entity-returned)

So unfortunately, LUIS doesn't have great support for Japanese at this time. The LUIS team is hoping to have major improvements to tokenization by August, 2019, which will greatly improve Japanese recognition.

Here's a few things you can try to improve your app:

1. Ensure that when you create the LUIS app, you select Japanese for the Culture
2. Ensure that you provide training examples for both Keigo and informal Japanese
3. Follow the [Best Practices Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-best-practices) - this is VERY helpful for generally improving your LUIS app

Comment: It’s September. Any update for tokenization of Japanese? @mdrichardson-msft

Comment: I don't believe so. You can watch for updates [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/whats-new)